# cant find a driver for HP AMD Radeon HD 6450 512MB PCIEX16 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon

I have been trying for quite some time to get a "HP AMD Radeon HD 6450 512MB PCIEX16" GPU to work. I have a HP 6200 Compaq pro SFF, so my gpu options were limited but I picked what I thought was the best of them. After installing the GPU, my PC would turn on but the screen stays black (so that kinda eliminates the option of Ubuntu installing the driver as far as I know). I'm guessing that's because it is trying to use the GPU I just installed instead of the imbedded graphics. I took the GPU out and scoured the BIOS and found no option to change anything GPU related in there (and it looks like others have had the same problem and just updated the BIOS, but on Windows). I checked the HP update list on Ubuntu's website, but my PC was not listed so I cannot update the BIOS that way either. I browsed through AMD's website, and I couldn't find anything for my particular GPU (although I'm new to linux in general so I could have looked at it and had no idea I was). I really don't feel like downloading Windows again at 200 kb/s just to update the BIOS then install Ubuntu again. Any ideas on how I can get this thing working?

Comment: Did you tried check the available proprietary drivers? "Configurations > addicional drivers."

Comment: My additional drivers page under "Software and Updates" is blank =(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking on unofficial ATI graphics wiki, saw tour hardware in supported list. http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

Please follow The steps listed here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks!! I installed what looked like the correct one, and after installation I could not access the files or find what I installed for some reason. I decided to power off my PC, pop in the GPU, and hope for the best- and it worked! I updated it from the additional drivers tab and it works! Still a bit sketchy in steam (left 4 dead 2 performs worse than it did with integrated graphics on Windows 8.1-it is pretty choppy and unplayable), but it runs some stuff! I don't need the distractions from my school work anyway ; ). Thanks again!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try going to the Unity search by clicking the top left icon in the Unity launcher. From there search "system settings" and you should find a program bearing the same name as the search. Click that and you should see an icon called "Software and Updates"; click there. Go to the last tab called "Additional drivers" and download whatever drivers you may deem necessary. I had to do the same thing with my old Geforce 6300. Hope it works!

Comment: I'll try that when I get back home and let you know if that worked. Thanks! But wouldn't the gpu have to be in the PC for it to install that? I had to take it out so I could see again =(

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for me =\. It can't detect drivers for stuff that's not in my PC, unless there's something I'm missing. Thanks, tho!